# Determine unique phone attribute that scanned a QR code

Tags: php, qr-code

All,
I'm allowing a user to scan a QR code and when they do I'd like to identify them by an attribute on their phone. Is there something that I can use or get from the mobile device (since they can use an iPad and not just a phone) to distinctly identify the user that scanned the QR and doesn't change like an IP address?

I'll know all my users who will be scanning the QR code so I'm trying to get a static and unique piece of information so I can identify them do they don't have to select their userid.

Please let me know if anyone has had any experience doing something like this.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the app which is scanning the code. If its a generic 3-rd party app you can't trace the device which scanned the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the QR content is a URL you can simply set a Google Analytics tag on that URL.

Although that won't give you information about the people who scan your code but the ones who scan your code **AND** follow the URL, that is usually an acceptable trade-of.